# Why don't PrimeNG buttons classes work even if i have primeNG installed properly?

Tags: angular, button, primeng

My problem is that I can't design buttons using default classes in primeNG..

Steps that I took:
I have installed it in NPM locally.
I have added button modules into app-modules.
I have included it in angular.json.
- have included it in package.json.

This is how my webpage should look like:
[image: tutorial]

But this is how it actually looks like:

[image: my image]

I am not sure why.

Comment: Did you add them to the styles array in angular.json or styles.css file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the styles/css that comes as a part of primeng?

If not, try adding these to the `styles` array in `angular.json`/`.angular-cli.json`(Depending on your Angular version)

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  //...
],
```

**OR Better**

Add them to the `styles.css` file:

```
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, the second one worked like a charm.